# Copy custom post types and admin

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm copying over a site from a former developer. I've installed a new instance of wordpress and database on new server, copied all but the wp-config from old server to new, but in admin it does not show the custom post types that are showing in old admin. I would think that these settings are in the functions.php, but I'm copying that over. Shouldn't they show? How can I make this work?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you activate the theme that was used at the previous site?

Comment: What plugins were used in the previous site?

Comment: Yep activated. I moved two other sites over in this fashion that had custom post types... didn't work there either so just used a pluging to re-create them. This third on had 10 (!) custom post types (geesh) with a bunch of additional categories linked to post-types. It's a mess. Webord... alot of plugins but nothing for custom post types on the original site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the custom post types won't show until you call register_post_type.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

this was either done in a plugin or the theme that you were previously using.  if you are no longer using those you will have to activate it again yourself.  i suggest making it a plugin (and possibly even an mu-plugin)

Comment: Hi and thanks! I'm sure it's not a plugin but here is a list that are used for reference (below).

Shouldn't that move over if I'm copying all files (in wp-content, wp-admin and wp-includes as well as root files except wp-config because I want it attached to my database) ?

Thnks again! Plugins used:

Google Analytics
Google XML Sitemaps
Gravity Forms
JF3 Maintenance Redirect
jQuery Colorbox
Pronamic Google Maps
Quick Cache
Relevanssi (Dramatically improves the performance & speed of your site! Also compatible with WordPress® Multisite/Networking.)
Search Everything
WordPress SEO
WP-Cufón

Comment: afaik, none of those plugins have to do w/ CPTs.  if it wasn't a plugin, then it must've been the old theme that registered the post type.  have you activated the same theme you were using?  i don't like themes registered post types for exactly this reason.  i still recommend moving all the post types/taxonomies to a plugin so this doesn't happen again.

Comment: I agree with you, I just don't understand how to make it work. I'm not that great with taxonomies... really confuses me.

Comment: Yes activated the same theme. So not sure why it wouldn't show.

Comment: was there an mu-plugins folder in wp-content? you have to have missed something. they didn't just magically appear.  registering them yourself if not that hard, see the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: So take a look at some screengrabs: 1. Here's the filezilla ftp showing all plugins http://grab.by/c5nW  and 2. the admin page showing the custom post types with additional variables, etc. http://grab.by/c5nU

Comment: no /mu-plugins is another folder, separate from /plugins . what theme are you using?

Comment: Custom theme developed by someone else. I did a search... no folder named mu-plugin anywhere. I feel like I'm loosing my mind :)

Comment: that usually means that it is time to quit and have a glass of wine.  if you can search the contents of the theme, look for register_post_type and register_taxonomy

Comment: Are those .php files? Or should that be in functions.php? I talked to an expert that said I needed to export the old database and that would do the trick... seems to me like customization should be in the theme level, yes?

Comment: By the way... no files names that or anything in functions.php in the theme folder.

Comment: exporting the database only gets the data.  if you don't initialize the post type WP will leave it in the DB and never think twice.  register_post_type and register_taxonomy are wordpress FUNCTIONS.  and there is NO way that you got Feature, Artist, Event, etc as post types without something, somewhere calling register_post_type. if you have notepad++ search the whole damned folder.  trust me on the wine thing though...  ;)

Comment: Wow that was completely mental. Thanks!!! Found it in functions.php.

Comment: looks like you needed fresh eyes.  though if you have that theme activated them the register_post_type should be running (unless someone removed the action hook)  glad you sorted it out.